# Multi-threading Indy IdHTTP requests. Performance consideration issues

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy, pausing-execution

My application queries 7 marketplaces in a row using Indy HTTP client. All marketplaces provide a unified interface to request/response. That said, the structure of request/response is the same for all 7 marketplaces.

I submit [GTIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number) to a MainForm's `TEdit` box and the app posts 7 RESTful requests to the marketplaces and returns XML responses for all of them.

My idea is to wrap each request in a separate thread, but I am really concerned by the performance issues. Normaly I perform 1 request in 3-5 seconds.

Each thread is created in a `for` statement and initalizes `TIdHTTP` object, makes a request, gets an XML-response, parses it and ships it back to the MainForm.

When the job is done each thread needs to be terminated (or paused?)
If the thread completely terminates, then it must perform the same initialization routine on a next request. I find it relatively slow, assuming 7 thread initializations at a time.

However, if the thread is paused it merely resides in memory, has all its factories initialized and is *ready* to accept next requests.

How do I leave the thread *operationally terminated*, **but still completely initialized**? I assume, if `TIdHTTP` and XML-parsing objects stay alive in a paused thead, they will act much faster on the next request. Does it have any sense?

Comment: I don't think that the time to create thread and objects is noticeable. Anyway, you create a loop in the thread Execute (while not Terminated do) which will process some queue and pass results into main thread using some event.

Comment: 3-5 seconds for 1 request? That's very slow. On most websites a request will take less than 0.2s.

Comment: @SpiderPig no-no... I mean, I submit requests to the MainForm every 3-5 seconds. That is an average interval to scan barcodes.

Comment: I seems that you are looking for a threadpool?

Comment: @whosrdaddy what is a definition of a threadpool? Actually I just want to keep all 7 threads alive to reuse the objects _already created_ inside them.

Comment: You can create a queue of requests, and a pool of running threads, where each thread goes to the queue, pulls out a request if any, processes it, and then goes back to the queue, repeating as needed. If the queue is empty, the thread waits/sleeps until a new request is in the queue. There are many different ways to implement a thread pool queuing system, too many to show here. You can use Win32 API I/O Completion Ports. You can use a third-party threading library like OmniThreadLibrary. Or even Embarcadero's own Parallel Programming Library in recent Delphi versions. This topic is very broad.